# Fit text in UILabel

Tags: objective-c, ios, uilabel

Here is my code

```
 UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 300, 50)];
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.textColor.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:30];
    label.text = @"A very long string";
     etc...
```

The problems is that the font is large and can't fit in the label. It just display "A very"

What to do so entire text to be displayed.
I have tried

```
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
label.numberOfLines = 0;
```

But it doesn't work for me.
I want to do that programmatically.

//EDIT

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(10, 50, 300, 50);
    NSString *labelString = @"Players.";

    UILabel *howManyUsersLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
    howManyUsersLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    howManyUsersLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    howManyUsersLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    howManyUsersLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
    howManyUsersLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

    CGFloat fontSize = 30;
    while (fontSize > 0.0)
    {
        CGSize size = [labelString sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:fontSize] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, 10000) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        if (size.height <= frame.size.height) break;
        fontSize -= 1.0;
        NSLog(@"test");
    }

    howManyUsersLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:fontSize];
```

Comment: The only 2 options reduce the font size or make the Rect bigger

Comment: Yes, but I think the question was how to calculate te correct font size at runtime if you don't know what the text is going to be in advance.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

I think you just need to add this:

```
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
label.minimumFontSize = 0;
```

Then the text will automatically resize to fit the label.

Note however that this will only really work if the label.numberOfLines = 1, so that the text is on a single line.

If you need the text to wrap onto multiple lines but still shrink to fit, the solution is more complex. To do this, you need to calculate the rendered size of the text and then reduce it in a loop, as follows:

```
NSString *theText = @"A long string";
CGRect labelRect = CGRectMake(10, 50, 300, 50);
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
label.numberOfLines = 0;

CGFloat fontSize = 30;
while (fontSize > 0.0)
{
    CGSize size = [theText sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:fontSize] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(labelRect.size.width, 10000) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    if (size.height <= labelRect.size.height) break;

    fontSize -= 1.0;
}

//set font size
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:fontSize];
```

This basically just reduces the font size until it fits the label.

**UPDATE:**

As of iOS7, multiline text will also shrink automatically when `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES`, so the second part of this answer is no longer needed (unless you still support iOS 6 and earlier).

Comment: Hm.. I get Use of undeclared  identifier constrainedToSize

Comment: Please see the updated code. The simulator just show black screen.

Comment: Oops sorry, see the new line at the end of the loop. I've also added a safety check inside the while (...). That'll teach me to write code in a hurry!

Comment: I do not want to be cheeky, but now the app is running but the label is not displayed

Comment: Make sur you add linebreakmodewordwrap to the label. Then if it still doesn't work, try putting an NSLog for the size.height in the loop and check that it's going down each time round the loop. Also log the eventual textSize. If it's zero somerhing's wrong.

Comment: I added NSLog(@"test"); at the end of while but there is no string "test" in the output. For some reason while statement is not executed. Please see the updated code.

Comment: If your text is just the word "players" it probably fits already the first time, so the loop will exit at the break the first time round, so that's as expected. I suspect it's not showing  for some unrelated reason. Take out all the resizing code and see if you can get the label to appear without it, then put the loop back in.

Comment: Well, I increase the labelString. Now I get null as a output in NSLog(@"%@", size.height);

Comment: I don't think you're setting label.text = labelString anywhere. That's probably why it's invisible. Also you should log height using %f not %@.

Comment: `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` does nothing, useless. The only function it has is reducing text if it is bigger than container's width. So it does nothing if text is smaller than container's width

Comment: @user25 if you want to scale your text *up* to fit the label, you could set it to a much larger font size than required, then adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth will scale it down to the correct size.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I got solution for text allignment issue in arabic language you just do like this:

```
    label.text = @"هذا هو نص طويل جدا";
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentNatural;

    CGSize size = [labels sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(_lblAddress.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
    label.height = size.height;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[UILabel sizeToFit];
```

It will work for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift with iOS 9**

```
let maxFontSize: CGFloat = 40
let minFontSize: CGFloat = 10

label.font = UIFont(name: label.font.fontName, size: maxFontSize)!
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
label.minimumScaleFactor = minFontSize/maxFontSize
```

This doesn't increase the font size to fill the label. It just starts with the max size and decreases as necessary down to the minimum. This is also assuming that the number of lines is 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
CGRect titleRect        = CGRectMake(10, 50, 300, 50);

UILabel *textTitleView  = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:titleRect];

textTitleView.numberOfLines = 3  //for multiple lines;

textTitleView.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:30];

textTitleView.text          = @"your text";
```

Comment: This doesn't address the issue of overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Interface Builder lets you do this now.

1. In UILabel, under Autoshrink, select **"Minimum Font Size"** instead of "Fixed Font Size".
2. Set the **Minimum Font Size** to be something reasonable, like 8.
3. You can also check the checkmark **"Tighten Letter Spacing"**.

Alternatively you can do it programmatically:

```
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

Comment: minimumFontSize is deprecated in iOS 6 - use minimumScaleFactor instead.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to be broken in iOS 8 (probably iOS 7 too).

### Solution:

```
-(UIFont*)fontForString:(NSString*)string toFitInRect:(CGRect)rect seedFont:(UIFont*)seedFont {
    UIFont* returnFont = seedFont;
    CGSize stringSize = [string sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : seedFont}];

    while(stringSize.width > rect.size.width){
        returnFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:returnFont.pointSize -1];
        stringSize = [string sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : returnFont}];
    }

    return returnFont;
}
```

Make sure you don't try and use `label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES` otherwise it'll get really confused and the new size won't work properly.